# Picasso memory/disk cache

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I use Picasso to download images from the web, and display them in a RecyclerView.

```
private Picasso createPicasso(Context context){

        OkHttpClient picassoClient = new OkHttpClient();

        picassoClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {

                try {

                    Map authHeaders = BackendServiceClient.buildAuthHeaders();

                    Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", (String) authHeaders.get("Authorization"))
                            .build();
                    return chain.proceed(newRequest);

                } catch (CredentialNotStoredException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder().build());
            }
        });

        return new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(picassoClient))
                .build();
    }
```

Usage:

```
  ImageDownloader.getSharedInstance().getPicasso(context)
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.head_big) //
            .error(R.drawable.head_big) //
            .tag(context)
            .into(holder.personPhoto);
```

Downloading and displaying the images works as expected, but if I scroll through the list, the images gets fetched from the web again and were not cached.
How is it possible to **always** cache them on the disk and memory.

Comment: .... the server side has to support caching ...

Comment: There is no way forcing caching the images on disk?

Comment: the first google search with right keywords returns a creator's of this library answer ... never underestimate the power of the google search

Answer (score 1):

Switched to Glide which improves memory footprint and caching works out of the box.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en